# Remote Linux compilation with MSBuild

Tags: linux, msbuild, cross-compiling

Good morning,

MSBuild requires Visual studio 2017/19 to be installed on the PC where it runs, in order to be able to compile C and C++ on a remote linux environment.

I would like to know if there is a way to remote compile with only MSBUILDTOOL installed on the Windows PC ? (so without VS 2017 or 2019)

Thx
manu

Answer (score 0):

There is a component called **Build Tools**, you can install it and use msbuild without installing *Visual Studio*.

Comment: Hello Baruch and thank you. 
VS offers at installation "Linux development for c++" which allows c++ linux cross compile feature. Buid Tools for VS but does not offer that option at installation. Thx 
manu